# Changing value in multidimensional hash

Tags: ruby

I'm using the Cinch IRC framework to make a quote function that allows users to CRUD quotes.

I'm running into a problem; I based my iteration on the cinch-quote gem, which uses YAML to store the quotes.

It loads the quotes from YAML into a multidimensional hash. The delete_quote method needs to find the marked quote by ID, and mark it 'deleted' in the YAML database. The problem I'm having is with changing the deleted value from false to true in this YAML DB. I'm new to ruby and this code is probably absolutely awful and laughable, please be brutal.

```
  def get_quotes
    output = File.new(@quotes_file, 'r')
    quotes = YAML.load(output.read)
    output.close
    quotes
  end

  def delete_quote(m, search = nil)
    if is_admin?(m) && search.to_i > 0
      quotes = get_quotes
      quote = quotes.find { |q| q["id"] == search.to_i }
      #debugging stuff
      #returns the master quote hash
      p quotes
      #returns the hash that i'm trying to change.
      p quote
      if quote.nil?
        message_type(m, "Quote ID #{search} does not exist.")
      else
        #again, master hash
        output = YAML.load_file(@quotes_file)
        #here's the error. Can't convert Hash into Integer. I can't figure out why
        # it'd be generating that, or how to fix it.
        mark_delete = output[quote]["deleted"] = "true"
        message_type(m, "Quote #{search} was deleted")
      end

    end
  end
```

Comment: YAML.load_file(@quotes_file)   #Meet your new get_quotes method

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed a small sample of the YAML and the equivalent Ruby object returned by YAML after loading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already found the quote by using:

```
quote = quotes.find { |q| q["id"] == search.to_i }
```

Why query the file one more time?

Instead, just mark it as deleted:

```
quote['deleted'] = true
```

Then dump the quotes into YAML and save the file.